# Problems Centering Elements and Creating Boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm building a little play HTML page as I teach myself how to code. I've watched several walkthrough videos and want to incorporate what I've learned without watching the video so that it sticks better. Here is an image of what I'm dealing with.

[image: Page]

I want these three sections, **'Learn HTML'**, **'Learn CSS3'**, and **'Learn Javascript'** to be centered on the page. I created a `<section ID="">` tag to center everything on the page under the showcase and 3 separate `<div class="">` for each box.

My problem is two-fold, not only are the border boxes not centering on the page, but the boxes aren't even appearing.

Here's the code...

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFAF0;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topheader {
  background-color: #228B22;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('../coding/codage.png');
  background-position: center right;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#main {
  width: 33.3% padding:10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top {
  float: left;
  border: 3px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ByMyself.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How To Build A Website By Yourself</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="topheader">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Learning HTML5 and CSS3</h1>
    </div>
  </header>


  <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learning HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learning CSS3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>How to learn how to build a website from scratch! Code The Future!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="clr"></div>

  <section id="main">
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn HTML5</h2>
      <ul>
        <ol>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</ol>
        <ol>Step 2 - Take Notes</ol>
        <ol>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn CSS3</h2>
      <ul>
        <ol>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</ol>
        <ol>Step 2 - Take Notes</ol>
        <ol>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn Javascript</h2>
      <ul>
        <ol>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</ol>
        <ol>Step 2 - Take Notes</ol>
        <ol>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- **FLOAT**: What you need to do is apply both a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** (of about a third) and a **[`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** to your three `.top` elements. Note that the `width` should take the margins into consideration, which can be achieved by subtracting them with the **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function. I've gone with `margin: 0 20px;` for a horziontal marign of`20px` and no vertical margin, along with  `width: calc(33% - 40px);`, which takes both the left and right margins into consideration before finding `33%` of the available `width`.
- **BORDER**: You've applied a rule of `border: 3px black`, which is **almost** right; you're looking for **[`border: 3px solid black`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)**; the *`solid`* is critical!

In addition to this, your 'list items' are **[`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)**, which stands for ordered list. You've essentially got multiple ordered lists inside of an unordered list. These should be **list items** (**[`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)**) instead, inside of `<ol>` items, which would look like:

```
<ol>
  <li>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</li>
  <li>Step 2 - Take Notes</li>
  <li>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</li>
</ol>
```

However, having said that, you'd benefit from simple **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** tags instead, as each point wants to be on its own line, and you're adding your own "Step 1" prefixes.

This can be seen in the following (click `Run Code Snippet` then `Full Page`):

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFAF0;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topheader {
  background-color: #228B22;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('../coding/codage.png');
  background-position: center right;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#main {
  width: 33.3% padding:10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: calc(33% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ByMyself.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How To Build A Website By Yourself</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="topheader">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Learning HTML5 and CSS3</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learning HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learning CSS3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>How to learn how to build a website from scratch! Code The Future!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="clr"></div>

  <section id="main">
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn HTML5</h2>
      <div>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</div>
      <div>Step 2 - Take Notes</div>
      <div>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn CSS3</h2>
      <div>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</div>
      <div>Step 2 - Take Notes</div>
      <div>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      <h2>Learn Javascript</h2>
      <div>Step 1 - Watch Tutorials</div>
      <div>Step 2 - Take Notes</div>
      <div>Step 3 - Repeat Until It Sinks In</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!